# RegexExtract in Google Sheets for all occurences of seed list?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to extract a comma separated list of matching phrases in Google Sheets.

I have a Named Range 'Matchlist' =

1. sit amet
2. Ut enim
3. commodo consequat

Cell A1 =

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
> eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
> aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

In cell B1 the desired output would be:

> sit amet,Ut enim,commodo consequat

I have been trying to use REGEXEXTRACT to do, but can only output the first match....
Any ideas or alternatives?

Comment: I would do one at a time (each in own column) and then concatenate the lot using `TEXTJOIN()`

Comment: Any ideas on how to do one at a time? I can only ever get the first match from the list; ARRAYFORMULA(PROPER(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A1), LOWER(TEXTJOIN("*|", 1, Matchlist))))))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(SPLIT(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "(sit amet)|(Ut enim)|(commodo consequat)", "♥$1$2$3♦♥")), "♥")), "♦"), 
 IFERROR(SPLIT(IFNA(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A, 
 "(sit amet)|(Ut enim)|(commodo consequat)", "♥$1$2$3♦♥")), "♥")), ))
 ,,99^99))), "♦$", ), "♦", ","))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! Can't seem to get working with the actual text / a seed list but will keep fiddling.